# Date of Birth Drop Down using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to create a DOB dropdown using ng-options. I have some how created it for day & month but while creating for year the issue i am facing is , my drop down displays years properly in reverse order i.e. starting from 2014 - 1915 but the value property displays values from 1 to 100 instead from 2014 - 1915. Can you also suggest a better way to do it. i find this way little lame. I dont want to use ng-repeat

HTML

```
<select class="day" id="DateOfBirth_Day" name="DateOfBirthDay" required ng-pattern="\d+" ng-model="user.question5.answer.dobday" ng-options="o for o in days">
    <option value="DD">DD</option>
</select>
<select class="month" id="DateOfBirth_Month" name="DateOfBirthMonth" required ng-pattern="\d+" ng-model="user.question5.answer.dobmonth" ng-options="o for o in months">
    <option value="MM">MM</option>
</select>
<select class="year" id="DateOfBirth_Year" name="DateOfBirthYear" required ng-pattern="\d+" ng-model="user.question5.answer.dobyear" ng-options="o for o in years">
    <option value="YYYY">YYYY</option>
</select>
```

Controller Code

```
 $scope.user = {
     question5: {
        answer: {
            dobday: 'DD',
            dobmonth: 'MM',
            dobyear: 'YYYY'
        }
     }
}
$scope.totaldays = 31;
$scope.totalmonths = 12;
$scope.totalyears = 100;
$scope.days = ['DD'];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totaldays; i += 1) {
    $scope.days.push(i + 1);
}

$scope.months = ['MM'];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalmonths; i += 1) {
    $scope.months.push(i + 1);
}

$scope.years = ['YYYY'];
for (var i = 2014; i > 2014 - $scope.totalyears; i--) {
    $scope.years.push(i - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `ng-repeat` with `<option>` tag instead `ng-options`

```
<select class="year" id="DateOfBirth_Year" name="DateOfBirthYear" required ng-pattern="\d+" ng-model="user.question5.answer.dobyear" >
    <option value="YYYY">YYYY</option>
    <option ng-repeat="o in years" value="{{o}}">{{o}}</option>
</select>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1011/)**</kbd>

Comment: I am actually new to angular, just want to know the best practise so is it recommended to use ng-repeat instead of ng-options when actually what we are generating is a select tag

Comment: right, if you want to add `value` or `title`, use above mentioned way